How to set pointers of pointers such that they map consecutive areas of memory
I am a bit of a newbie in C++ and wanted to work on a implementation of an algorithm, for it I need to allocate space for various matrices which I did in the following way (DATA_TYPE is double in this case):
void initializeMatrix(DATA_TYPE**& matrix, int rows, int cols) {
  matrix = new DATA_TYPE*[rows];
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    matrix[j] = new DATA_TYPE[cols];
  }
}

So that I can access the values inside the matrices like matrix[i][j], looking back though I see that it was not a smart decision as when I access different rows, they may be stored far away in the memory with the consequence that I lose performance because of lack of spatial locality. How can I rewrite this function so that I still can work with a DATA_TYPE** but the various DATA_TYPE* pointers to the rows are spaced by #cols and possibly also aligned.
Does the following implementation make sense (on Windows)? I am aware that I still lose some performance as everytime I call matrix[i][j] I am losing time fetching the memory address of the row. Is there a way to circumvent it or at least improve on it (Maybe storing the DATA_TYPE** close to where the values are stored).
void initializeMatrix(DATA_TYPE**& matrix, int rows, int cols) {
  size_t total_elements = rows * cols;
  size_t alignment = sizeof(DATA_TYPE);
  DATA_TYPE *start_index = (DATA_TYPE *)_aligned_malloc(total_elements * sizeof(DATA_TYPE), alignment);
  matrix = (DATA_TYPE **)malloc(rows * sizeof(DATA_TYPE *));
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    matrix[j] = start_index+j*cols;
  }
}


Usually we do the opposite, we allocate a "1D array" and use 2 indexes access like index = col + row * ncol

Depending on how you overload operator[], matrix[i][j] can be compiled down to simple pointer + offset calculation. No pointer chasing required.

Consider to use std::vector instead of raw C arrays. This fits well with the good suggestion in the 1st comment (to use a 1D array).

Well, there is a placement-new which allows you to create objects (e.g. arrays) in a pre-allocated storage (static, dynamic or automatic). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new There is no obvious need for that to implement matrix but it essentially answers to your question. You should use OOP to impelement matrix and manage that though, because would have to manage that allocated array.

@Fareanor I know, but I already wrote the rest of the code to match the double pointer format so I need to patch the way I create the matrix somehow.

@luri why you adding C++ code to a C program?

"but I already wrote the rest of the code to match the double pointer format" - see the accepted answer here.

I actually thought of another possible workaround, just allocate one large data chunk and pass a single pointer to the DATA_MATRIX, this way I only need to access the DATA_TYPE** matrix only once

Here is a brain-dead simple 2d matrix class:
template <class T>
struct Matrix {
    Matrix(int rows, int cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols), m(rows * cols) {}
    std::vector<T> m;
    const int rows, cols;
    T* operator[](int i) { return &m[i*cols]; }
    const T* operator[](int i) const { return &m[i*cols]; }
};

The overloads of operator[] allow you to write:
double getMiddle(const Matrix<double>& m) {
    return m[5][5];
}

and have it compile down to a single pointer calculation.

returning a std::span would be better i think.

I did say it was brain-dead simple  There is also no bounds checking whatsoever.
